# What is the best way for sum numbers at a big text file?

Tags: python-2.7, bigdata

What is the best way for sum numbers at a big text file?
The text file will contain numbers separated by a comma (',').
The number can be from any type.
No line or row limits. 
for example:
1 ,-2, -3.45-7.8j ,99.6,......
...
...

Input: path to the text file
Output: the sum of the numbers

I am tried to wrote one solution at myself and want to know for better solutions:

This is my try:
I am working with chunks of data and not read line by line, and because the end of the chunk can contain some of the number (just -2 and not -2+3j) i am looking just on the "safe piece" the last comma (',') and the other part save for the next chunk

```
import re
CHUNK_SIZE = 1017


def calculate_sum(file_path):
    _sum = 0
    with open(file_path, 'r') as _f:
        chunk = _f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            chunk = chunk.replace(' ', '')
            safe_piece = chunk.rfind(',')
            next_chunk = chunk[safe_piece:] if safe_piece != 0 else ''
            if safe_piece != 0:
                chunk = chunk[:safe_piece]
            _sum += sum(map(complex, re.findall(r"[+-]\d*\.?\d*[+-]?\d*\.?\d*j|[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?", chunk)))
            chunk = next_chunk + _f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        return _sum
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not really following this description.  Please read the [mcve] guidelines and provide a working example with sample input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: I add the expected input and output,
Thanks.

Comment: @MarkTolonen why the minus points? What missing?

Comment: "path to the text file" doesn't describe the input.  What is the content of the input file? Provide a real example.  "the summary of the numbers" isn't the output.  What is this summary supposed to look like?  Your code doesn't print anything.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Hi friend, thanks for your answer, I am edited my question.
add the content of the file and change from summary to sum.
I really hope that it's more clear now...

Answer (score 0):

This will add up any amount of numbers in a text file.  Example:

**input.csv**

```
1,-2,-3.45-7.8j,99.6
-1,1-2j
1.5,2.5,1+1j
```

**example.py**

```
import csv

with open('input.txt','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    total = 0
    for line in r:
        total += sum(complex(col) for col in line)

print total
```

**Output**

```
(100.15-8.8j)
```

If you have really long lines and insufficient memory to read it in one go, then you could use a buffering class to chunk the reads and split numbers out of the buffer using a generator function:

```
import re

class Buffer:

    def __init__(self,filename,chunksize=4096):
        self.filename = filename
        self.chunksize = chunksize
        self.buf = ''

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            while True:
                if ',' in self.buf or '\n' in self.buf:
                    data,self.buf = re.split(r',|\n',self.buf,1) # split off the text up to the first separator
                    yield complex(data)
                else:
                    chunk = f.read(self.chunksize)
                    if not chunk: # if no more data to read, return the remaining buffer and exit function
                        if self.buf:
                            yield complex(self.buf)
                        return
                    self.buf += chunk

total = 0
for num in Buffer('input.txt'):
    total += num
print total
```

Output:

```
(100.15-8.8j)
```

Comment: but what if all the file is one huge line? (FILE_SIZE > 20G)

Comment: @Naor88 Then that requirement should have been in the question.

Comment: it's there... "No line or row limits"

Comment: Nice solution!  
I don't see better time performance when I measure between the two..

Comment: @Naor88 I wasn't going for efficiency and it could definitely be improved.  `in` scans the buffer each time for `,` and `\n` for example.  If this solution works for you, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.